# Replace text with html tag in filter

Tags: html, angularjs, filter

in my form body I have this (example):

```
<div class="a" ng-repeat="q in question">{{q.Type}}</div>
```

the result would be :.

```
<div class="a ng-scope" ng-repeat="q in question">2</div>
```

question contains the user questions , and the Type in the type of the message like "System" , "Modules", and other things .

so the values are :

1: System,

2: Modules,

3: ...

here is the topic question :

I want to change the Type to image . the meaning is I want to replace the Type in {{q.Type}} with  tag . so I try to use filters and I changed my code to this :

```
<div class="a" ng-repeat="q in question">{{q.Type | imgReplace}}</div>
```

and the I wrote my filter and then in filter I have something like this :

```
if (input == 2) {
     return "<img src='img.jpg' />";
```

but the result is :

```
<div class="a ng-scope" ng-repeat="q in question"><img src="modules.jpg" /></div>
```

what can I do for this situation . it dont render the html tag and render a plain text .

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is better to use `ng-class`

HTML:

```
<div class="a" ng-repeat="q in question" ng-class="marker(q.Type)">{{q.Type}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.marker = function(val) {

    switch (val) {
        case "1":
            return "class1";

        case "2":
            return "class2";

    }

}
```

and set `background-image` to class1 or class2

Comment: oh ! your right . and i can use text-indent to hide the text and use the default option in switch to show that when i wanted to. nice one . thanks .

Answer (score 2):

May be you are after this:

```
ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"
```

at this div:

```
<div class="a" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml" ng-repeat="q in question"></div>
```

and in your controller/directive you can add this:

```
$scope.html = "<img src='img.jpg' />";
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

---

What i meant here you need to use `$sce` in your controller to tell angular that this img is coming from trusted source so treat it as a markup not as a string and with this you can use your filter as you needed.

### [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8TdeTNMMYubQRZpt8Wij?p=preview)

Comment: i think you misunderstood me . there is a different data . its 1 , 2 , 3 or 4 . and not the same value for every record . i have to make switch between these values for different img src.

Comment: @Dr.Bronx i just updated the answer with a plunkr and you can see what i meant to say, `$sce` should be used to tell angular to treat the coming markup as markup not string.